# Hide Link Button of ItemTemplate from Grid View

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVCoresponding" runat="server">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit" ShowHeader="false">

<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnedit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" ></asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
   <EditItemTemplate>
   <asp:LinkButton ID="btnupdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update">
   </asp:LinkButton>

   <asp:LinkButton ID="btncancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel">
   </asp:LinkButton>
</EditItemTemplate>

</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

> my Questtion

Above All from my Grid View. I want to Hide the LinkButton of EDIT when my following condition is occurred:

#### Code Behind

```
if (Session["dept"].ToString() == "RiskAdmin") 
    {
        ????????

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `RowDataBound` event for this

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      if (Session["dept"].ToString() == "RiskAdmin") 
      {
          LinkButton lnkBtn = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("btnedit");
          lnkBtn.Visible = false;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Successfully Done. Many Many Thanks Brother